# python function complains about global variable not being defined

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

when I moved the code into functions the calculation will not work now. Complains:
NameError: global name 'feet' is not defined
How do I fix this so the method sees the variable correctly?

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/ 10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass

def frame():
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    feet = StringVar()
    meters = StringVar()
    feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, justify = CENTER, textvariable = feet)
    feet_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = meters).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (W, E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Calculate", command = calculate).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = (W))

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "feet").grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = (W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "is equivalent to:").grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = (E))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "meters").grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = (W))

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    feet_entry.focus()
    root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

# create a Tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title("Menu Bar")
frame()

# start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: On what line is the error reported?

Comment: It looks like you have your feet and meters variables defined in frame(), but use them in calculate(). Try defining the two variables outside frame() so that they are visible to both functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make `feet` and `meters` instance attributes by replacing them everywhere by `self.feet` and `self.meters`, to get

```
        value = float(self.feet.get())
        self.meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/ 10000.0)
    ...
    self.feet = StringVar()
    self.meters = StringVar()
    feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, justify = CENTER,
                           textvariable = self.feet)
    feet_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = self.meters
             ).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (W, E))
```

Comment: when I do replace feet and meters with self.feet and self.meters everywhere I get:    self.feet = StringVar()
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: sorry bro but your answer didn't work.  maybe you can down check your answer and upcheck my question now.

Comment: That would work if the app was in a `class`, which it isn't. Just define `feet` and `meters` outside any fuction, so before you call `frame()`, like MirekE suggested in his comment on the question. Or rewrite the app to be in a class, then you can use self to pass variables around.